# How to get season as JJAS instead of JJA in xarray?

Tags: python, mean, python-xarray

How to get monsoon months (JJAS) in xarray while calculating seasonal mean instead of JJA?

```
import xarray as xr
fname='/home/krishna/SIMS/P1/*.nc'
ds=xr.open_mfdataset(fname)
temp=ds.temp
sea_temp=temp.groupby('time.season').mean(dim='time')
sea_temp.plot.imshow(col='season',robust=True)
```

the output shows in JJA month instead of JJAS. 
How can I calculate seasonal mean for JJAS (June-September)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could resolve this issue by writing a function as follows

```
def is_jjas(month):
    return (month >= 6) & (month <= 9)

seasonal_temp = temp.sel(time=is_jjas(temp['time.month']))
```

I hope this will help someone who has the same doubt doing seasonal mean for the Indian summer monsoon season (JJAS).

Comment: This looks great; I think you probably want `month >= 6` for the interval to start in June, however :).

Comment: Yeah.. @spencerkclark I really forgot that point. Thanks for rectifying the error I made.